# Windows Phone 8 Timer Picker Control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am working on Window Phone 8 app. The problem is that i need to show Timer picker control on any button click event so i was not able to do this task so please can any one help me to out of this problem ?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack overflow! If you are looking for help for your problem, you will need to explain where exactly you have had problems (code snippets are extremelly useful for this!). Regards.

Comment: Have a look at the [The Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)  there is no TimePicker in the normal control set

Answer (score 0):

XAML::

```
 <xctk:TimePicker Name="StartPicker" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="StartPicker_TextChanged" Value="{Binding StartTimeBinding, ElementName=MainWin, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" Height="50" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
```

CS::

```
private void EndPicker_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartPicker.Focus(); // shows error at TimePicker Name(i.e StartPicker)
        }
```

use Windows Phone Toolkit Package.